# Django: is_valid() method is always false why?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, forms

Everytime i get the stu_name variable value from form without using is_valid() function then stu_name is always return value enter by user but with is_valid() stu_name is always None.I do some experiments and i found that is_valid() is always return false but why?

This is views.py file code.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import student
from .forms import student_data

def my_data(request):
    stu_name=None
    myform=student_data(request.POST)
    if (request.method=="POST" and myform.is_valid()):
        stu_name=myform.cleaned_data['user']
    else:
        myform=student_data
    return render(request,'show.html',{'student':stu_name})
```

This is my html file where the form code is written.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="/payment/show/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" required>
            <label for="">ID</label>
            <input type="number" required>
            <label for="">Address</label>
            <input type="text" required>
            <button type="submit">Add Me</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py file code.

```
from django import forms

class student_data(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length=20)
    id=forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput,max_value=6)
    address=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length=50)
```

Comment: The only named field on your form is `user` and your form is  expecting `name`, `id`and `address` to be present...

Comment: The form input names on your HTML dont match up to the names of your form object. You onlyhave name="user" , nothing for id or address.

Comment: @JonClements thanks now my code is working actually i'm new to django and i even don't know php,so i'm noob in server-side programming.thank you again. one more question why we need to define forms in form.py.Does form define in forms.py is collecting data from form created in html file.i'm about confused about it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your view

```
def my_data(request):
    stu_name=None
    myform=student_data(request.POST)
    if (request.method=="POST" and myform.is_valid()):
        stu_name=myform.cleaned_data['user']
    else:
        myform=student_data
    return render(request,'show.html',{'student':stu_name,'form':myform})
```

In your html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="/payment/show/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit">Add Me</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in your forms.py

```
class student_data(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length=20, required=True)
    id=forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput,max_value=6, required=True)
    address=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length=50, required=True)
```